# Can I appear offline on steam but still be online?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, garrys-mod

I have a friend that won't stop pestering me to play tf2, I don't want to be mean to him but when I want to play another game like gmod with another friend I would be in offline mode. Because I would be in offline mode I can't join his server on gmod. Is there any way that I can appear offline but not actually be offline , as in I can still see my friends online but can't see me online?

Answer (score 3):

You have to click on Friends button and select Offline. It will show you as offline in friends list, but you will still be online on steam. You won't be able to see your friend list, but you can still play with them if you join through other means (web profile or game browser within the game).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't joining a server kick you out of "offline to friends mode"?

Comment: @LawsontheJedi It won't - according to my experience, being offline will hide you from appearing online, but it will still track your achievements and hours played if I am not wrong.

Comment: @LawsontheJedi friend list is just an integrated IM application. Your friend list has no effect on anything else going on on steam.